# Assign to *this for constructor delegation

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, this, delegation

I was looking at some of the new features in C++11, and due to my current version of GCC I am unable to use constructor delegation.  But it got me thinking about replicating the feature like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : num( 42 ) {}
    A( int input ) { *this = A(); num *= input; }

    int num;
};
```

It certainly compiles and works fine, the code below:

```
A a;
cout << "a: " << a.num << endl;
A b( 2 );
cout << "a: " << b.num << endl;
```

Returns this, which is correct.

```
42
84
```

Obviously this is a very trivial example, but other than the memory inefficiencies (two `A`'s created and one overwritten by the other before being destroyed), what problems could arise?  It certainly looks like a code smell, but I can't think of a really good reason why.

Comment: Btw, GCC 4.7 will have constructor delegation (it's already in trunk)

Comment: I know, this question is really out of curiosity.  I'm currently running v4.6, I'll wait until my distro upgrades me and then I can do this 'properly'.

Comment: Does the type not being assignable counts toward a limitation :) ? (with move assignment, it's unlikely to arise often).

Comment: Have you thought about `new (this) A;`? (I have _no idea_ if that's even remotely valid, but avoids the memory allocs - looks even dirtier though :) )

Comment: @Mat: It is not valid (you may only placement new into raw memory, an object already exists there) and before you suggest to call the dtor before that, read the corresponding gotw about why this is poison for exception safety.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: thanks, didn't know that was discussed somewhere - http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/023.htm - interesting indeed.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Assuming the 'requested from' constructor does not allocate any heap memory before the 'requested' constructor is called, surely placement new is fine?  And G++ certainly thinks it is legal, on stack or heap.

Comment: @cbamber85: be careful with `<compiler>` thinks its legal. Compilers aren't required to diagnose all UB conditions. They can detect and diagnose _some_ (and sometimes do), but just because g++ doesn't throw a fit doesn't mean its kosher. It doesn't even mean g++ _thinks_ it ok.

Comment: @cbamber85: Just because something "works" on a compiler, doesn't mean it is not UB. Being obvious UB in case of certain constructors, but not in others, should ring a bell that the standard would certainly not make such a complex decision.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: That's wrong, the lifetime of an object ends when you reuse its storage. `new (this) A;` definitly counts here, though you'll have problems with a non-trivial destructor if you don't call the destructor beforehand (which results in exception safety problems), but it's totally valid.

Comment: @Xeo: that is only true for class types with non-trivial dtor, see §3.8-1

Comment: For another reason, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030769/calling-another-constructor-when-constructing-an-object-with-const-members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing your object with the integer, but modifying a default initialized object. This might or might not be an issue. Quite often people factor common stuff out in some `init()` function to have similar functionality as delegating ctors. However, there are some situations in which this is not desired/wrong/impossible:

- when you have a reference member, you must initialize this in the ctor, you can not default initialize it and later overwrite. Using a pointer instead can help.
- for certain members, default initialization does something, and overwriting does something additional. Performance wise, it would have been more efficient to right away initialize the member. Depending on what the initialization does, this might just be a performance hit, but for certain side-effects of the object, it might even be plane wrong.
- The member might not be assignable.

Additionally, this is just considered bad style by some people. I personally consider it bad style because I think you should always initialize instead of assign later, even for simple cases, since one day you forget it for an important case and then the lost performance bites you.

But YMMV.

Comment: I am currently using an init() function, but I was hoping for a cleaner idiom - and didn't find one!  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not actually C++11 at all. I was thinking whether move constructors might work here as you are essentially moving one A into another then modifying it slightly.

As with C++03, you can optimise the initialisation you want to perform once in all your constructors either by putting them into a sub-class or a base-class (often with protected or private inheritance as it's an implementation detail). Using a base class:

```
class ABase
{
protected:
  int num;

  ABase() : num(42) {}
};

class A : protected ABase
{
public:
   A() = default; // or in C++03 just {}
   explicit A(int input) : ABase()
   {
       num *= input;
   }
};
```

(You can modify your access permissions to taste). The issue here is I only ever create one "ABase" object and if it has more than just a trivial int member, that might be significant. I quite like the inheritence as I then use it in A as a class member rather than a member of some aggregated object, and I prefer the inheritence protected or private here but sometimes if the base class has members I want to be public, I will use public inheritence but give the base class a protected destructor. This is assuming there is no v-table and thus no further derivation is expected. (You can finalize A here actually by making the inheritance virtual and private but you probably don't want to).

Comment: I know my example code isn't C++11 - that's the whole point of the post (emulating constructor delegation pre-C++11).  Your solution does solve the problem of initialising references (which can't be done in an `init()` function), but it also takes more LOC and extra types.