# Calling another constructor when constructing an object with const members

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

I have a class with `const` members, and one constructor which calls another constructor with extra values filled in. Normally I could use a colon initializer for this, but the function is complex (`printf`/`sprintf`-like) and requires me to use a variable on the stack, so I have to do this in the body of the constructor and use assign `*this` to the new object. But of course this is invalid, because my member variables are `const`.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int b) : b(b), c(0), d(0) // required because const
    {
        int newC = 0;
        int newD = 0;
        myfunc(b, &newC, &newD);
        *this = A(b, newC, newD); // invalid because members are const

        // "cannot define the implicit default assignment operator for 'A', because non-static const member 'b' can't use default assignment operator"
        // or, sometimes,
        // "error: overload resolution selected implicitly-deleted copy assignment operator"
    };
    A(int b, int c, int d) : b(b), c(c), d(d) { };

    const int b;
    const int c;
    const int d;
};

A a(0);
```

(I haven't explicitly deleted the assignment operator.) I declared the members const because I would like them to be public, but not mutable.

Is there some canonical way of solving this problem without using scary casts and force-overriding the members' `const`ness? What's the best solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a parameters class and use either C++11 constructor delegation or a base class:

```
struct parameters {
    int b; int c; int d;
    parameters(int b): b(b), c(), d() {
        myfunc(b, &c, &d);
    }
};

// constructor delegation
class A {
public:
    A(int b): A(parameters(b)) { }
    A(parameters p): b(p.b), c(p.c), d(p.d) { }
};

// base/wrapper
class ABase {
    ABase(parameters p): b(p.b), c(p.c), d(p.d) { }
};

class A: public ABase {
public:
    A(int b): ABase(parameters(b)) { }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

How about making a helper function:

```
class A
{
    static int initializor(int b) { int n; myfunc(b, &n); return n; }
public:
    explicit A(int b_) : b(b_), c(initializor(b_)) { }
    A(int b_, int c_)  : b(b_), c(c_)              { }

    // ... as before ...
};
```

Comment: I like this idea! — the tricky part is that I actually have more than one variable so it's more like `myfunc(b, &c, &d, &e)`. Is there a way to do this for multiple variables?

Comment: @jtbandes: Maybe a `A make_A(int, int, int)` function that computes the necessary terms and returns an appropriately constructed `A`?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [Kerrek SB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12030792/396551), but in your case there is the complication that you can't easily make separate initialisation functions for each member.

In that case, another solution is to move the members to a base class and initialize that base class with a helper class with non-const members. Your initialization code is moved to the helper class' constructors, and can assign without problems.

```
class A_init
{
  public:
    A_init(int b)
    {
      // do whatever you like with c and d:
      c = ...;
      d = ...;
    }

    int c; // Note: non-const
    int d; // Note: non-const
};

class A_base
{
   public:
     A_base(int b, A_init init) : b(b), c(init.c), d(init.d) {}
     A_base(int b, int c, int d) : b(b), c(c), d(d) {}

     const int b;
     const int c;
     const int d;
};

class A : public A_base
{
  public:
    A(int b) : A_base(b, A_init(b)) {}
    A(int b, int c, int d) : A_base(b, c, d) {}
};
```

If one wants restrict access to `A_init`, one can switch to private and declare `A` a friend.

Answer (score 0):

Where to put the results of `myfunc` so it can be set and used from different mem-initializers?  How about in a default argument?

```
class A
{
private:
    struct InitData;
public:
    A(int b, InitData data=InitData());
    A(int b, int c, int d) : b(b), c(c), d(d) { };

    const int b;
    const int c;
    const int d;
};

struct A::InitData
{
    int setup(int b);
    int c;
    int d;
};

inline int A::InitData::setup(int b)
{
    myfunc(b, &c, &d);
    return b;
}

inline A::A(int b_, InitData data)
    : b(data.setup(b_)),
      c(data.c),
      d(data.d)  {}

A a(0);
```

Since the made up type is private and has no conversions, there's little risk of accidentally using it or abusing it.

Comment: I would like to add that initialisation is done in the order of the **declaration** of the members and not in the order in the initialisation list. Here the two agree, so there is no problem. But suppose someone moves 'const int c;' before 'const int b;', then you suddenly would have a bug in `A::A` as `c(data.c)` would be executed before `data.setup(b_)` would have been called.