# c++ How to use a ctor from another ctor?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling another constructor when constructing an object with const members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030769/calling-another-constructor-when-constructing-an-object-with-const-members)

I want the latter to use the former. How can i do that in c++?. If it's not possible why can't i make the `*this = regMatrix` assignment?

```
RegMatrix::RegMatrix(int numRow,int numCol)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numRow;i++)
    {
        _matrix.push_back(vector<double>(numCol,0));
    }
}

RegMatrix::RegMatrix(const SparseMatrix &sparseMatrix)
{
    RegMatrix regMatrix(sparseMatrix.getNumRow(),sparseMatrix.getNumCol());
    vector<Node> matrix = sparseMatrix.getMatrix();
    cout << "size: " << matrix.size() << endl;
    for(std::vector<Node>::const_iterator it = matrix.begin(); it != matrix.end(); ++it )
    {
        cout << "Position: [" << (*it).i << ", " << (*it).j << "] Value:" << (*it).value << endl;
        regMatrix._matrix[(*it).i][(*it).j] = (*it).value;
    }

    *this = regMatrix;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the new C++0x using "Delegated Constructors".
`

```
RegMatrix(const SparseMatrix &sparseMatrix) : RegMatrix(sparseMatrix.getNumRow(),sparseMatrix.getNumCol())
{
    vector<Node> matrix = sparseMatrix.getMatrix();
    cout << "size: " << matrix.size() << endl;
    for(std::vector<Node>::const_iterator it = matrix.begin(); it != matrix.end(); ++it )
    {
        cout << "Position: [" << (*it).i << ", " << (*it).j << "] Value:" << (*it).value << endl;
        this->_matrix[(*it).i][(*it).j] = (*it).value;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: tried to do that and put the following code in the header file but i get syntax error: `(RegMatrix::RegMatrix(const SparseMatrix &sparseMatrix) : RegMatrix(int numRow,int numCol);)`

Comment: Remove the last ;) (fixed above). What version of what C++ compiler are you using.

Comment: I change the definition but still i get syntax error: `RegMatrix(const SparseMatrix &sparseMatrix) : RegMatrix(int numRow,int numCol);`

Comment: Are you not using the member variables in the call to the function ? Also there shouldn't be a ';' at the end. Basically the call which you made inside the code earlier nedes to go as an "initialization' sort of a constructor.

Comment: i'm reffering to the declaration in the header file

Comment: The declaration doesn't change actually. It should be just RegMatrix(const SparseMatrix &);

Comment: @ArnuMK oh no.. now i get:type ‘RegMatrix’ is not a direct base of ‘RegMatrix’

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22797/discussion-between-arunmk-and-tom)